# Overlay over WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, overlay

I have a TabControl (using InfragisticTabControl) where each TabItem contains a WebBrowser control where I can display a URL like www.google.com or any xbap UI.

Below is the TabItem Code:

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="myBrowser"
            webHelper:WebBrowserHelper.BrowserSource="{Binding XBAP_URI}"
            Height="Auto"/>

    <Grid Name="MyOverlayGrid" Background="LightGray" Opacity="0.5" 
          Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible2}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type igDock:ContentPane}}}">
        <TextBlock Text="User does not have permissions for this application" FontSize="24"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I verified using snoop that Visibility binding is correctly getting populated, but I don't see MyOverlayGrid on myBrowser control. I even tried updating Panel.ZIndex for MyOverlayGrid, no help.

Only thing that worked is to set myBrowser visibility to hidden (i used snoop) and then i could see MyOverlayGrid.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing something incorrect or missing something obvious? This works fine for a contentcontrol, may be its not possible for a WebBrowser control since the its starts new applictaion (InternetExplorer.exe or PresentationHost.exe) in the tab control?

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527667/overlay-for-webbrowser-control-in-wpf-application

Comment: @Akansha, thanks for the useful link. It helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me if I am doing something incorrect or missing something obvious?

The latter am I afraid. The `WebBrowser` control is hosted in a separate HWND that is *always* drawn on top of the WPF elements as stated in the documentation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744952(v=vs.110).aspx.

There is nothing much you can do about this besides applying a workaround like for example putting your `Grid` in a `Popup`.

You may want to consider using some other third-party `WebBrowser` control such as for example [Chromium](http://wpfchromium4.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks @mm8, i was not aware of airspace issue. I am using popup control to fix this.